# neural network estimation of compositions distribution

Tags: neural-network

To use feed forward neural network to predict compositional distribution, e.g.fractions of nutritions, vitamin 10%, protein 35%, water 35%, fat 20%, for each composition sample, sum composition percentages of all nutritions equal to 1.

My question is, for predicting such compositional distribution, what activation function should I use at output layer? It looks similar to regression problem, but sums of each dimension of a single composition data must equal to one, which similar to logistic regression or softmax. Should I use softmax? or linear as activation function at output layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but sums of each dimension of a single composition data must equal to one

This appears to be a multiclass prediction, softmax will be good. In logistic regression, the sums of prediction may not be equal to one.

Comment: Why this is multi class prediction? the value it predicts is percentage of each category.